# Big M Equality Constraints Question

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I am a newcomer to mixed integer linear programming, and I am having some trouble using the Big M method to linearize some constraints, and was wondering if I implementing it incorrectly.

Here is what I want to do:
$$ y_{i-1} + x_{i-1}\cdot Eff==y_i\quad when \;x\ge0$$
$$ y_{i-1} + x_{i-1}\cdot \frac 1{Eff}==y_i\quad when \;x\lt0$$

In order to linearize this constraint, I added a binary indicator variable and used the Big M method, converting this to 6 constraints.

These first two would force $B_i=1$ when $x_{i-1}\ge0$ and $B_i=0$ when $x_{i-1}\lt0$ using a big enough M:

$$ x_{i-1} + M \cdot (1-B_i) \ge 0$$
$$ x_{i-1} + M \cdot B_i \lt 0$$

Then I divided each of the equality constraints into two inequality constraints each, using the big M and the binary variable $B_i$ to remove the constraints that are not applicable.  I figured this would force only one of the greater than/less than sets of equations to be a true constraint:

$$ y_{i-1} + x_{i-1}\cdot Eff + M \cdot (1-B_i)\ge y_i$$
$$ y_{i-1} + x_{i-1}\cdot Eff - M \cdot (1-B_i) \le y_i$$

$$ y_{i-1} + x_{i-1}\cdot \frac 1{Eff}+ M \cdot B_i \ge y_i$$
$$ y_{i-1} + x_{i-1}\cdot \frac 1{Eff} - M \cdot B_i \le y_i$$

However, when I run the actual code of this model, the general constraint $y_{i-1} + x_{i-1}\cdot Eff==y_i$ is not being followed, and I think it must be the way I am implementing the big M methodology.  Can anyone tell if what I am doing is incorrect?  Thanks! (apologies for mistakes, I'm new to all this)

Comment: So in your solution $B_i=1$ yet $y_{i-1} + x_{i-1} \neq y_i$? Then this might be a scaling issue: $M$ is too large relative to your data.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, $y_{i-1}+x_{i-1} \ne y_i$ (including $Eff$ multiplication or division).  I have tried adjusting $M$ such that it is small enough, but still have same problem.

Comment: Please share an iteration log from the solver in the node that gives the final solution.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean exactly (sorry, total beginner), is it this: MIP - Integer optimal solution:  Objective = -1.6027290000e+00
Solution time =    0.02 sec.  Iterations = 0  Nodes = 0
Deterministic time = 1.00 ticks  (62.79 ticks/sec)  It is not including constraints so objective is incredibly easy

Comment: If $x_{i-1}>0$ and $B_i=1$, your second inequality containing $M$ is violated. I think you want the + to be a -. Also, it's not possible to enforce a strict inequality (in your case, $x_{i-1} < 0$) in a proper MIP formulation. Either you need to let $B_i$ be ambiguous (either 0 or 1) when $x_{i-1}=0$, or you need to force $B_i=0$ when $x_{i-1} \le -\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, and prohibit $x_{i-1}\in (-\epsilon, 0)$.